# Oracle sub-partition shows data, but oracle query using filter does not show data

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g, I have created fact table with date as partition and site_id as sub-partition.

analyse is running daily on this table. but based on one day interval, analyse step is performed.

In SQL DEVELOPER tool, when I open table definition, under partition tab, I am able to see the partition as 23-JAN-2016. For all site_ids, I am able to see sub-partition.

```
Select * from NPM.EH_MODEM_HIST_PRFRM_FACT subpartition(SYS_SUBP1256625);
```

When I run the above query, I am able to see the data.

But I am running below query using report sql; but table is not fetching data

```
select * from  NPM.EH_MODEM_HIST_PRFRM_FACT
where time_stamp ='23-JAN-16' and site_id =580
```

Is there any problem in managing this table?

Comment: Probably wrong timestamp literal format.

Comment: we have moved this table since 6 days. It is working perfectly for all sub-partitions on all 6 days except this one single sub-partition.

Comment: Is `time_stamp` a column in your eh_modem_hist_prfrm_fact table? If so, what datatype is it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you're actually after is something like:

```
select *
from   NPM.EH_MODEM_HIST_PRFRM_FACT
where  time_stamp >= to_date('23/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    time_stamp < to_date('23/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1
and    site_id = 580;
```

The above assumes that the datatype for the time_stamp column is `DATE`. If it's actually `TIMESTAMP` then you should use the SQL below:

```
select *
from   NPM.EH_MODEM_HIST_PRFRM_FACT
where  time_stamp >= to_date('23/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
and    time_stamp < to_date('23/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + interval '1' day
and    site_id = 580;
```

Note also that I have specified the date with a four digit year. Two digit years are just soooo pre-y2k! *{;-)